# How to make a loop that go up and down at the same time?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, loops

i was wandering how to make a loop that go up and down at the same time.

For example, here is the normal loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++){}

for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i--){}
```

How can i simplify this loop?

Comment: `for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i--){}` does not make sense!

Comment: Just use `let j = number.length - i - 1` in the first line of the loop?

Comment: I think Javascript has the notion of negative indexing, so the true way to do this in a single loop might be to use a periodic counter: `for(let i = 0, j = Math.sign(number.length - i - 1) * (i % number.length); i < 2 * number.length; i++)` and access on `j`. That way you guarantee that  the first `number.length` items are from indices `[0, number.length - 1]` and the second are in `[0, -(number.length - 1)]`. Technically done in one loop and in the correct order but certainly harder to understand and computationally expensive.

Answer (score 6):

You can have as many indexes as you want in a `for` loop:

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for (let i = 0, k = a.length - 1; i < a.length && k >= 0; i++, k--) {
    console.log(i, k)
}
```

or, you can compute the second index from the first

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let k = a.length - 1 - i
    console.log(i, k)
}
```

If you want to do that in the modern way, without any indexes at all, this would require some runtime support:

```js
function* iter(a) {
    yield* a;
}

function* reversed(a) {
    yield* [...a].reverse();
}

function* zip(...args) {
    let iters = args.map(iter);
    while (1) {
        let rs = iters.map(it => it.next());
        if (rs.some(r => r.done))
            break;
        yield rs.map(r => r.value);
    }
}

//

a = 'abcdef'

// just like in python!
for (let [x, y] of zip(a, reversed(a)))
    console.log(x, y)
```

Comment: Great answer!  Call me old school, but the modern way is sometimes a microcosm of bloatware...  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just embed 2 loops. Such as:

```
for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++){  // i going "up"
  for(let j = number.length; j > 0; j--){}  // j going "down"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values from first to the last value and vise versa at the same time you don't have to use double loops. Instead just use the i and arrays length. Here's an example.

```
var length = number.length - 1
for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
   console.log(number[i])
   console.log(number[length-i])
}
```